# How to update enhanced grid with new data

Tags: dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid, dojo

I have an enhnaced grid connected to a JSONRest and i have it populating after the grid starts up. 
I'm confused as to how to update the Grid store when a new query is performed, can anyone help ?

```
    var store = new JsonRest({
        target: "rest/search"
    }); 

    dataStore = new ObjectStore({ objectStore: store });

            /*set up layout*/
    var layout = [[
       {'name': 'Name', 'field': 'col1', noresize: true, 'width': '100%'},
    ]];

    /*create a new grid:*/
    grid = new EnhancedGrid({
        id: 'grid',
        store: dataStore,
        structure: layout,
        selectable: true,
        selector: false,
        selectionMode: 'none',
        escapeHTMLInData: false,
        autoHeight:true,


        plugins: {
          pagination: {
            pageSizes: ["10", "25", "50"],
            description: true,
            pageStepper: true,
            maxPageStep: 4,  
            defaultPageSize: 5,
            sizeSwitch: true,
            position: 'bottom'
          }
        }
      }, document.createElement('div'));


    grid.setQuery({
        term: "term",
        category: "category"
      });

    grid.startup();
```

Doing a store.query does hit my back end, but how do i repopulate the Grid with the results?

```
    store.query({term: "newterm", category: "newcategory"},
              {
                start: 10,
                count: 10,
              }).then(function(data){





              });
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to populate the grid, you shouldn't be performing a store query directly - you should be instructing the grid to use the store, and it will query it itself.

You already appear to be assigning the store instance in your call to the DataGrid constructor, and you're properly wrapping it with `dojo/data/ObjectStore` (since dojox grid doesn't support `dojo/store`), so it's not clear to me why you are even attempting to perform a query beyond that.  You should see a network request to your service as soon as you call `grid.startup()`.

If you're seeing a network request being made when you create the grid but you're not seeing results in the grid, chances are your service does not actually follow the conventions that `dojo/store/JsonRest` expects.  See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/quickstart/rest.html for information on what is expected in requests and responses.

If you're actually asking how to tell the grid to use a different store at some point in the future, call `grid.setStore(newstore)`.

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for replying... 

"In order to populate the grid, you shouldn't be performing a store query directly - you should be instructing the grid to use the store, and it will query it itself."

I think this is what i'm doing in the first block of code above.. when the grid starts up it calls my rest service succesfully passing in the parameters it needs (using the grid.setQuery() method)...

what i'm trying to do is then call the service again with new parameters and update the store attached to the grid with the results of this new call, this is where im struggling. how do i do this?

Comment: Oh, ok, it sounds like what you want then is `grid.setQuery({ term: "newterm", category: "newcategory" });`

Comment: hi Ken, using grid.setQuery s second time doesnt seem to call my server....  If i set up the grid and call it the first time it hits the server but when i call it the second time it doesnt hit the server with my new criteria... im stumped!

Comment: @KenFranqueiro The link provided in your answer is old and out to date(DEPRECATED, read the first line of the article).

Comment: * out to date = outdated

Comment: Apparently at some point all of the quickstart pages were marked as deprecated in favor of the tutorials on dojotoolkit.org, but there are a couple which are still quite useful and aren't available in tutorial form, this being one of them.  Nothing in dojo/store/JsonRest (let alone dojox/data/JsonRestStore) has changed to make that page any less accurate.