# How to change a Dojo EnhancedGrid store to a new store on button click?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm using the latest version of Dojo (1.10.4).

The default grid shows up just fine and performs as expected but I need it to changes it's store when a query is put into the input field and the button is clicked. The structure should remain the same as well as all the settings. I just want to grid to be changed to information present in the new store.

HTML

```
<h1 align="center">Submissions</h1>
<input type="text" id="query" name="query"></input><button class="srButton" onclick="changeGrid();">Search</button>
<div id="allSubGrid" ></div>
```

JS

```
var newGridQuery;
var grid, dataStore;
changeGrid = function() {
    require([
             "dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid",
             "dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/Pagination",
             "dojo/store/Memory",
             "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
             "dojo/request",
             "dijit/registry",
             "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(EnhancedGrid, Pagination, Memory, ObjectStore, request){
        var newGrid = registry.byId("allSubGrid");
        newGridQuery = document.getElementById('query').value
        alert("REACHED");
        request.get("http://localhost:8080/webapp/resultsBeta/"+ newGridQuery +".json", {
            handleAs: "json"
            }).then(function(data){
                dataStore = new ObjectStore({ objectStore:new Memory({ data: data.submissions }) });
                newGrid.store.close();
                newGrid.setStore(dataStore);
                newGrid.render();
            });
    });
}

require([
         "dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid",
         "dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/Pagination",
         "dojo/store/Memory",
         "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
         "dojo/request",
         "dojo/domReady!"
], function(EnhancedGrid, Pagination, Memory, ObjectStore, request){

    request.get("http://localhost:8080/webapp/submissions.json", {
        handleAs: "json"
    }).then(function(data){
        dataStore = new ObjectStore({ objectStore:new Memory({ data: data.submissions }) });
        grid = new EnhancedGrid({
            store: dataStore,
            items:data.items,
            autoHeight: true,
            rowSelector: '20px',
            structure: [
                { name: "Submission ID", field: "id", width: "7.5%" },
                { name: "Filename", field: "filename", width: "10%" },
                { name: "Submitted By", field: "username", width: "10%" },
                { name: "Time", field: "time", width: "10%" }
            ],
            plugins: {
                pagination: {
                    pageSizes: ["25", "50", "100", "All"],
                    sizeSwitch: true,
                    pageStepper: true,
                    gotoButton: true,
                    maxPageStep: 4,
                    position: "bottom"
                }
            }
         }, "allSubGrid");
         grid.startup(); // Start grid

         grid.on("RowClick", function(evt) { // On row click do something
            var idx = evt.rowIndex, rowData = grid.getItem(idx);                
            require(["dijit/registry", "dijit/layout/ContentPane"], function(registry, ContentPane) { // on row click open up a new submission tab based on ID
                var tab = new ContentPane({
                    title: 'Sub: ' + rowData.id,
                    closable: true,
                    href: 'submissions/' + rowData.id + '/',
                    id: 'sub_' + rowData.id
                });
                var tabContainer = registry.byId('subPanel');
                tabContainer.addChild(tab);
                tabContainer.selectChild(tab);
            });
         }, true);       
     });
 });
```

Comment: Have a look over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20098820/how-to-update-enhanced-grid-with-new-data). Hope it helps.

Comment: @frank, that isn't quite the same question/answer, since that question didn't actually involve setting a new store.  That said, I thought that `grid.setStore(newStore)` should be enough to accomplish this, which the code above seems to be doing.  (I didn't think the `render` call should even be necessary.)

Comment: @Ken: Just setting the store wouldn't refresh the grid with new data. We do need to render it as I faced similar issue and when I called render method after setting the store then only grid was populated with new data.

Comment: I managed this by using newGrid.startup() after setting the new store . Maybe this little change would solve your Problem too.